# Insertar texto en un input con python

Tags: html, python, ajax, django

Tengo un formulario en HTML y al hacer click en el botón quiero que el input llamado desc se rellene con un valor x, como deberia hacerlo?

```html
<form  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Numero de cuenta</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ncuenta" placeholder="Numero cuenta" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Seleccionar empresa de la cuenta</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="comder_imerc" name="empresa">
          <option value="bancox">Banco x</option>
          <option value="bancoy">Banco y</option>
       </select>
    <div class="form-group"></div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-comder btn-lg">Buscar</button>
</form>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Descripcion cuenta</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Descripcion cuenta" required>
</div>
```

El método trae los valores del HTML y busca una cuenta, de momento solo imprime por consola el texto de lo que quiero mostrar en el input llamado desc.

```py
def du_modificar(request):
    context = dict()
    ncuenta = request.POST.get('ncuenta')
    empresa = request.POST.get('empresa')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = Repo().unaCuenta(ncuenta,empresa)
        lista = query

        for x in lista:
            print(x[1])

    return render(request,'cuentas/modificar.html',context)
```

Comment: para ello debes usar ajax te sugiero revisar esto: https://www.techiediaries.com/python-django-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es hacerlo con AJAX y JavaScript/jQuery para que no tengas que refrescar la página entera.

Para realizar búsquedas y traer información se usan peticiones de tipo GET no POST como estás haciendo. Obviamente quitando el token CSRF.

En tu caso sería conveniente realizar un nuevo método para consumirlo desde el front con AJAX que te devolviera únicamente el campo `desc` que requieres a partir de los campos de búsqueda.